# Parsing logs - single sql query, multiple loops OR multiple sql queries, no loops

Tags: php, mysql, loops, grouping

I am trying to work out the best way to parse the log files I store for my website as I want to create graphs for the following items

- hits per day over past 7 days
- hits by country code
- hits by referral url
- hits by browser

As every single 'hit' is logged, there are literally xxx,000 results returned and I'm unsure what would be the most efficient way of grouping the results. At present I'm looking at the following methods:

```
$sql =mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE sub = 'www' AND code = '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($code)));

while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    // hits per country
    if (isset($res['country_code'])) {$stat['cc'][$res['country_code']]++;}

    // hits by referrer
    if (isset($res['referrer'])) {$stat['rf'][$res['referrer']]++;}

    // hits by day
    if (isset($res['click_time'])) {
        $date = strtotime($res['click_time']);
        $date = date("d/m", $date);
        $stat['dt'][$date]++;
    }
}
```

This, I think is a pretty crude way of doing things, but with my limited skills was the best I could put together. Essentially it just loops through the sql results, putting each country code into its own array and adding a hit for it. It needs lots of refinement but it does work to an extent.

The other more traditional way Ive considered is multiple sql statements with grouping:

```
$query1 = "SELECT count(`country_code`) as country_num,`country_code` FROM `logs` GROUP BY `country_code`";
$result= mysql_query($query1);

$user_agent = "SELECT count(`user_agent`) as browser_num,`user_agent` FROM `logs` GROUP BY `user_agent`";
$browser= mysql_query($user_agent);

$referrer_url = "SELECT count(`referrer`) as ref_num, referrer FROM `logs` where referrer!='' GROUP BY `referrer`";
$result_ref= mysql_query($referrer_url);

$last_month= mysql_query("select count('click_time') as day_num, click_time from logs where click_time between '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."' GROUP BY DAY(click_time)");
```

Question is, which one would be quicker....and if neither are particulary efficient, what alternatives are there?

Cheers

Comment: have you test it? the two above..

Answer (score 0):

The first threee examples in the bottom block of code are very efficient if you set the right indexes. That's what MySQL does - spits out "groups" "sums" and "counts" very nicely. Indexes are critical to getting good efficiency, though.

The top block of code you need to get all the data and pull it into php, then loop using your own code (less efficient than the pre-compiled SQL functions). So you waste bandwidth and CPU cycles.

[The last one (group by DAY()) not so, but adding the right index will also help there.]

BUT - and here's the hard part, it's a balancing act. If the SQL server is busy, you may want to move some functionality to the web server (web servers can be load balanced, DB servers no so easily). And each index adds time/resource when adding/editing records. So only create when required. So run test, then run some more tests. No other way, really, for huge data sets.

Comment: Thanks, thats great (and kinda what i was expecting someone to say). Next question then is whether the 4 sql statements could be combined into one or two statements? And if so, would there be any performance benefit in doing so?

Comment: Quick answer: No. You have different "group by"s, and you can't combine those. Your next step for potential optimisation is to "denormalise" the data, this means keep running tallies of some data that you can refer to more quickly, as opposed to always going back to raw data. e.g. you have a daily process ("cron job") that calculates daily totals and you use that for reporting, or you update a second "running tally" table when you update the log. This way your indexes and the data to be processed are smaller, but it's more complex to handle. Again, a trade off - test it and test again.